# How to correctly insert from differently encoded text files?

Tags: python, sqlite, encoding

I have *.txt files generated by NetApp XCP and an Excel document with a list of file names. I am trying to insert data into database and compare two tables on column `file_name`.

Each file contains some characters which are not utf-8. I can't ignore characters as file path and file name are needed as final result. I tried module chardet with utf-8 ASCII MacRoman and some others (script is not finished yet). File names contain Chinese characters that when I insert into database end with '?' instead.

I need to insert into database from differently encoded files and compare file names for matches. I also need to bring back original path and file name so the files can be accessed.

```
def upload_leaked_files():
    #df = pd.read_excel(LEAKED_FILES, sheet_name=0) #,  encoding_override='cp437') #not working with pd.read

    with open(LEAKED_FILES, encoding="MacRoman") as file: #MacRoman
        data = list(csv.reader(file, delimiter=","))
    LeakedFile.objects.all().delete()
    bulk_group = []
    for row in data:
        #print(type( row[0]),row[0])
        d = row[0] #.encode(encoding="utf-8")
        #print(type(d), d)

        bulk_group.append(LeakedFile(file=d))
    LeakedFile.objects.bulk_create(bulk_group, batch_size=100)
```

Example file name: 预批量检验证明NCS低线仪表预批量件质量明.doc

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with encoding set to "utf8" and it seems to do the job:

Test file content:

```
预批量检验证明NCS低线仪表预批量件质量明.doc,someothertext
预批量检验证明NCS低线仪表预批量件质量明.doc,othertext
```

Code:

```
with open('./test_file.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8') as input:
    file_content = [r.replace('\n', '').split(',') for r in input.readlines()]
    
    rows = [r for r in file_content]
    print(rows)
```

Output:

```
[['预批量检验证明NCS低线仪表预批量件质量明.doc', 'someothertext'], ['预批量检验证明NCS低线仪表
预批量件质量明.doc', 'othertext']]
```

Am I missing something from your explanation?

Cheers :)

Comment: Works if files are saved as utf8 (which they are not).